# How to read an external html inside template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a situation where I need to render an external html within my ember application.  This external html is a fully formed html with its own css and js.  Is there a way to achieve this.

I have so far tried to create a property that returns html but it didn't work and did not throw an error.

Controller:

```
...
myhtml: function() {
   return this.get('C:\\file.html');
}.property('myhtml')
...
```

Template:

```
...
{{myhtml}} //also tried {{{myhtml}}}
...
```

Comment: Are you really calling `this.get('C:\\file.html')`, or is that just a pseudocode placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

First, your function should look like this:

```
myhtml: function () {
  <code here>
}.property()
```

You don't need to have `.property('myhtml')` at the end, because as far as I can see, that serves no purpose.

Now, what we want is to replace `<code here>` with some code that will returns a string containing the HTML of the page you want to show. Retrieving the HTML is asynchronous, meaning it will take some time. Thus, what you really want here is for `myhtml` to return a promise (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html):

```
myhtml: function () {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    <code here>
  });
}.property()
```

Okay, so now the basic idea is you want to use AJAX to retrieve the HTML of the page, and once you've got it, you want to call the `resolve` function on that HTML. That will be the trigger for `{{{myhtml}}}` in your template to display that HTML:

```
myhtml: function () {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: '<website-url-here>',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function (html) {
        resolve(html);
      },
      error: function () {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}.property()
```

That should do it.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Handlebars escapes anything included in {{}}, so won't this just render the escaped HTML onto the page? You could use {{{}}} but I think there will still be a problem as the question mentions the HTML including js/css and this doesn't seem like it would execute when added onto the page in this manner.

Comment: Yes, my answer does recommend using `{{{}}}`. If the OP simply wants to render all of the external HTML/JS/CSS into his template, my approach should work. However, if he wants it to be functional as a website within his own website, it will depend on the markup returned by the external site. Assuming the markup includes things like `<html>` tag, `<script>` and `<link>` tags inside a `<head>` tag, etc, then no, things won't display properly, and he's probably better off with an `<iframe>`.